# Web Api 2.0 working in postman but not in HTML page

Tags: .net, ajax, postman, asp.net-web-api2

Here's my controller code for web api 2.0 in .Net
When I use postman then it works fine but when I call it from a HTML page then I get error `No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI`
What am I doing wrong?

**Controller Code**

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult GetCustomerName (string num)
{
   return Json(new
   {
      success = true,
      message = "My Name "+ num,
   });
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://localhost:10000/api/CFP/GetCustomerName",
   type: "POST",
   data: {
            'num': '123'
         },
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   success: function (response) {
      alert(response.message);
   },
   error: function (xhr, error, thrown) {
      alert(xhr.responseText);
   }
});
```

**Error Screenshot**
[image: Error Screenshot]

**Postman Screenshot**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://localhost:10000/api/CFP/GetCustomerName",
   type: "POST",
   data: JSON.stringify({
            'num': '123'
         }),
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   success: function (response) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(response));
   },
   error: function (xhr, error, thrown) {
      alert(xhr.responseText);
   }
});
```

could you try above code , by stringifying the data

you can create the correct code from postman itself:

[image]

just clikc code and find the equivalent ajax code